# How to use Mongo ObjectId as a unique id in my DB

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I have a Large Mongo DB with raw web scraping data.  I have a process that reads the mongo docs and creates records in my MySQL reporting DB.  I need to track the documents that I have processed in the MongoDB.  I am trying to use the ObjectID but can't seem to convert it to a string.  I am using Pymongo as my client.

```
 for i in Coll.find({"ISBN": {"$exists" : True}})[20:50]:
        print('starting collection loop')
        #Check if doc has been processed
        if not ProcessingLog.objects.filter(mongoID = i['_id']).exists():
            mongoID = ProcessingLog(mongoID = i['_id'],source = 'amazon',createDate= datetime.datetime.now())

      ....
```

I get the following error

ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: What are you trying to do, your question doesn't give much over? Also it isn't a question

Comment: I am trying to log the Mongo docs that I have processed.  I don't want to delete them and I don't have write access to the DB.  I want to use the _id to create a record in my MySQL db with describing when I processed the file.  I am using PYmongo and cant seem to get a string from Mongo that I can store in my db and use to check to see if I have processed the doc next time my ingestion code iterates over the MongoDB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pymongo includes methods to work with ObjectId() as other type.

You can see what they are in the [docs here](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html).   You can probably make do with just str(o).

Comment: I have read the documentation and still can't get it to work.

Comment: what happens when you use str(i['_id']) instead of i['_id']?